# Condition on initial velocity vector to guarantee the existence of a curve that partially lies in a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $\Omega$ is a Riemannian sub manifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with boundary. For a $p \in \partial \Omega$ is there a way to compute a bound $\alpha_p\geq 0$ of the following kind. If $X_p \in T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ is such that $g_p(X_p,Y_p)>\alpha_p$ for every $Y_p \in T_p\partial \Omega$ with $g_p(Y_p, Y_p) =1$, then there exists a $\gamma: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\gamma(0) = p$, $\gamma'(0) = X_p$, and $\gamma(t) \in \Omega$ for every $t \in [0,\epsilon)$. Where $g_p$ denotes the canonical Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$

My intuition is that the value of $\alpha_p$ is related to the curvature of $\partial \Omega$ at $p$.

This question arose while I was trying to determine the set of feasible directions at $p\in \partial \Omega$, in a constrained optimization problem. I’ve tried to frame this question in a way such that the tools of differential geometry can be used.

Comment: Is the condition satisfiable? What about Y=0?

Comment: I agree, I should have said ... for all nonzero $Y_p \in T_p \partial \Omega$. Other than that I feel like the condition should be satisfiable. Perhaps further conditions on $\Omega$ are needed.

Comment: cool, I think you should update the question with that. I also think you should explain the problem more clearly in the question body (i.e. connect the title with the question body). include if you are making assumptions on the dimensions of these objects.

Comment: btw it’s impossible to have an $X_p\in T_p\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha_p>0$ such that for all non-zero $Y_p\in T_p(\partial\Omega)$, $g_p(X_p,Y_p)>\alpha_p$. This is because by simply taking a sequence of $Y_p$’s converging to $0$, you’d get the contradiction $0>\alpha_p$. So, at the least, you should fix the norm of $Y_p$, say $\|Y_p\|=1$. But still, it’s not sufficient, because you could replace $Y_p$ with $-Y_p$ and get a contradiction.

Comment: I suggest thinking about the standard manifold with boundary, $\Bbb{H}^n$, the upper halfspace, and work out the conditions you need in that case.